# Jquery DatePickers , Apply special class to some date pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am using date pickers at multiple places inside a five step wizard, Among one of the steps there is a need to only take month and year as input.

For that i made below changes,

```
$('#txtLivingSince').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
```

and also this css class

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
```

After applying this class all the pickers have hidden the calendar part. How can i Implement this without causing any changes in other picker values.

Comment: so you want your datepickers to take month and year as input ,then what are you trying to hide?

Comment: ui-datepicker-calendar is applied to all the datepickers, that is why the calendar is hidden. There are multiple ways to implement year and month inputs, the easy one is give dropdowns.